# Using Order by And Group By Together Eliminates some Records

Tags: mysql

```
user_id      date      
-------    ---------
1          1551867583
2          1551867580
3          1551867573
2          1551867543
2          1551867521
```

I have a similar table structure. What I want to do is to select records per user and select the latest one of each user's record.

Tried

```
GROUP BY profile_visits.user_id ORDER BY profile_visits.date DESC
```

This doesn't show all the latest records.

I searched and found this on StackOverflow

[group by and order by in mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41547252/group-by-and-order-by-in-mysql-query)

However, that solution didn't work for me

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: SO doesn't like "didn't work for me". SO likes "didn't work for me because...". See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I don't exactly know why it didn't work thats why I didn't write "because" !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use max date and group by

```
select max(date) max_date, user_id 
from  my_table 
group by user_id  
order by user_id, max_date
```

Comment: I guess max doesn't work with only unix timestamp?

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz   max()  is max for each data type  .. and unixtimestamp is just an numeric value

Comment: "MAX( profile_visits.date ) AS last_visit_date_time GROUP BY profile_visits.user_id ORDER BY last_visit_date_time DESC" When I run this I cannot see latest records

Comment: youre code  .. is not the code in your sample  .. anyway  .. my answer retunr the last date for each user  ..

Comment: OH It worked after I add user_id to order by. Thank you !!